# Show/hide navigation header depending upon platform in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, header, react-navigation

I want to show/hide header depending upon a platform in react-native. I have done this

```
  const RNApp = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Menu: {
      screen: Menu,
      navigationOptions: {
        gesturesEnabled: false,
        headerBackground: (
          <Image
            style={[
              StyleSheet.absoluteFill,
              {
                width: Metrics.screenWidth * 0.5,
                height: Metrics.navBarHeight * 0.6,
                marginTop:
                  Platform.OS === "ios"
                    ? Metrics.navBarHeight * 0.45
                    : Metrics.navBarHeight * 0.2,
                marginLeft: Metrics.screenWidth * 0.25,

                resizeMode: "contain"
              }
            ]}
            source={images.icons.headerimage}
          />
        )
      }
    },
    WebViewScreen: {
      screen: WebViewScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerVisible: Platform.OS === "ios" ? true : false,
        gesturesEnabled: false
      }
    }
  },
  {
    headerMode: "screen",
    initialRouteName: "Menu"
  }
);
```

This works if the platform is ios just like I want since there is no hardware back button there must be a header to navigate back. But with the above code the header is still visible in case of android too even with the condition I've given. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Checked the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#navigationoptions-for-screens-inside-of-the-navigator) and i'm not seeing `headerVisible`option there. Maybe you can use `header` option instead(?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a property `headerVisible`. The property that you are looking for is `header`:

> **header**
>
> React Element or a function that given HeaderProps returns a React
>   Element, to display as a header. Setting to null hides header.

In your case it has to be:

```
import { Header } from 'react-navigation'; // import the default header to use it for iOS

...

navigationOptions: {
    header: (headerOptions) => Platform.OS === 'android' ? null : <Header {...headerProps} />,
    gesturesEnabled: false
}
```

See also [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1444).